# Dividir em duas partes quando contiver mais de delimitador na string com explode

Tags: php

```
$produto = "Leite Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L"; 
$prod = explode(" ", $produto);
$prod[0]; //tipo_produto = Leite
$prod[1]; //marca_produto = Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L
```

Preciso que `prod[1]` guarde a sting inteira, incluindo as virgulas, mas quando executo o explode ele não me retorna a string inteira

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `explode` está configurado para dividir a string por espaços, na sua string claramente está toda com espaços:

```
$produto = 'Leite Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L';
```

Quando roda o `explode`, ele retorna um array assim:

```
array(
   'Leite', 'Pasteurizado,', 'Mucuri,', 'Integral,', '1', 'L'
);
```

Se você ler a documentação vai entender melhor como funciona o php e ou qualquer linguagem que vier a programar, no caso http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php:

> Retorna uma matriz de strings, cada uma como substring de string formada pela divisão dela a partir do delimiter.

Veja como funciona o explode:

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

O parâmetro opcional chamado `$limit` pode resolver o seu problema, faça assim:

```
<?php
$produto = 'Leite Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L';
$prod = explode(' ', $produto, 2);
echo $prod[0], '<br>';
echo $prod[1], '<br>';

print_r($prod);//Visualizar a array
```

O `2` indica que vai dividir a string em no maximo dois itens na matriz (array), o resultado será este:

```
Leite
Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L
Array
(
    [0] => Leite
    [1] => Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L
)
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mais uma da serie, parâmetros que você nunca lembra que existem +1 :D

Answer (score 6):

Pode utilizar a função `strstr()` para retornar o que estiver a direita da  string:

```
echo strstr('Leite Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L', ' ');
```

Retorna: `Pasteurizado, Mucuri, Integral, 1 L`

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, Criei uma string especial e dei o explode nela.

```
<?php echo $linha['tipo_produto'].'*'.$linha['nome_marca']?>
$prod = explode('*', $produto);
```